# NDepend and Inheritance Diagram in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, inheritance, ndepend

Is there a way to draw the inheritance tree diagram with NDepend? 
(I can only find the Dependency diagrams which are not good for me).

If not, does anyone know of a tool that can do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to generate Class Inheritance Graph with NDepend.
It is explained in the documentation [here](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx#Inherit).

Notice the proposed pattern:

- First query code elements you want to see in a dependency graph
- Second export the code elements matched in the query result, to the graph

That can be also applied to other kind of Graph:

- [Dependency Graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx#Dep)
- [Call Graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx#Call)
- [Coupling Graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx#Coupling)
- [Path Graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx#Path)
- [All Paths Graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx#AllPaths)
- [Cycle Graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx#Cycle)

Code query result can also be exported to the [NDepend dependency matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx), that is more suited to see other kind of code structure patterns:

- [Layered Code](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx#Layer)
- [Dependency Cycle](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx#Cycle)
- [High Cohesion - Low Coupling](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx#Coupling)
- [Too Many Responsibilities](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx#Responsability)
- [Popular Code Elements](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx#Popular)
- [Mutually Dependent](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx#Mutual)